# 'One or more selected libraries are already on the build path' error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I've been working on my new Java project and according to my need I was trying to setup the JCalendar external library on my project. But unfortunately, after adding the user library, whenever I've selected that it displaying the message on the top **'One or more selected libraries are already on the build path'**

[image: Here is the pictorial for the aforementioned problem]

1. I've removed all the libraries which I have installed previously.
2. I've searched several time on Google.com, but those results couldn't satisfy me.
3. I would like to get a better solution as early as possible. Thank you all.